# Is there any plugin that limits number of photos upload to a woo commerce product to 5

Tags: wordpress

Is there any plugin to limit the number of images uploaded to a woo-commerce product

I have  gone through different plugins but didn't find any that meets my  requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can set limit to post for max attachments.

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', 'limit_wp_handle_upload_prefilter');
function yoursite_wp_handle_upload_prefilter($file) {
  // This bit is for the flash uploader
  if ($file['type']=='application/octet-stream' && isset($file['tmp_name'])) {
    $file_size = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);
    if (isset($file_size['error']) && $file_size['error']!=0) {
      $file['error'] = "Unexpected Error: {$file_size['error']}";
      return $file;
    } else {
      $file['type'] = $file_size['mime'];
    }
  }
  if ($post_id = (isset($_REQUEST['post_id']) ? $_REQUEST['post_id'] : false)) {
    if (count(get_posts("post_type=attachment&post_parent={$post_id}"))>4)
      $file['error'] = "Sorry, you cannot upload more than four (5) image.";
  }
  return $file;
}
```

Comment: .is there any plugin to limit image uploads to one for the products only but not posts

Comment: You need to add limit for all products or only for one specific product  ?

Comment: or just need to add one product image max on each product .

Comment: I want to add one product image max on each product

Comment: add_action( 'add_meta_boxes' , 'remove_my_meta_boxes', 40 );
function remove_my_meta_boxes()
{
    remove_meta_box( 'woocommerce-product-images',  'product', 'side');
}

Comment: remove gallery by above hook. then you can add only featured image to product

Comment: I don't have coding experience knowledge in wordpress.I dont know what do u mean by hook.can u be little more clear..Thank u

Comment: you need to add above code to your functions.php in theme but you should use FTP to make changes in theme.  by above code your gallery section will remove then you will have only featured image meta box where you can add only one image .

Comment: if still any doubts i can help with team viewer :)

Comment: i have tried the code.its removing complete product gallery but i need product gallery but with one image only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201825/discussion-between-sowmya-vejerla-and-lakshman-rajput).